# How to export data frame as CSV in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I'm analyzing some data over a loop of 10 iterations, each of the iterations represents one of the data sets. I've managed to create a data frame with pandas at the end of each iteration, now i need to export each with a different name. here a take of the code.

```
for t in range(len(myFiles)):
    DATA = np.array(importdata(t))
    data = DATA[:,1:8]
    Numbers = data[:,0:5]
    Stars = data[:,5:7]
    [numbers,repetitions]=(Frequence(Numbers))
    rep_n,freq_n = (translate(repetitions,data))
    [stars,Rep_s] = (Frequence(Stars))
    rep_s,freq_s = (translate(Rep_s,data))
    DF1 = dataframe(numbers,rep_n,freq_n)
    DF2 = dataframe(stars,rep_s,freq_s)
```

Data frames DF1 and DF2 must be store separately  with different names in each of the loop iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create lists of DataFrames:

```
ListDF1, ListDF2 = [], []
for t in range(len(myFiles)):
   ...
   rep_s,freq_s = (translate(Rep_s,data))
   ListDF1.append(dataframe(numbers,rep_n,freq_n))
   ListDF2.append(dataframe(stars,rep_s,freq_s))
```

Then for select DataFrame use indexing:

```
#get first DataFrame
print (ListDF1[0])
```

EDIT: If need export with different filenames use `t` variable for `DF1_0.csv, DF2_0.csv`, then `DF1_1.csv, DF2_1.csv`, ... filenames, because python counts from `0`:

```
 for t in range(len(myFiles)):
     ...
     DF1.to_csv(f'DF1_{t}.csv')
     DF2.to_csv(f'DF2_{t}.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks, now as for the part of exporting, do you know how to export each one with a different name inside the loop? i'm trying not to do it manually. I come from a matlab background and it is possible in that environement, so i wonder if i can do the same here

Answer (score 1):

you can use microseconds from datetime, since it will be different

```py
from datetime import datetime

for t in range(len(myFiles)):
    DATA = np.array(importdata(t))
    data = DATA[:,1:8]
    Numbers = data[:,0:5]
    Stars = data[:,5:7]
    [numbers,repetitions]=(Frequence(Numbers))
    rep_n,freq_n = (translate(repetitions,data))
    [stars,Rep_s] = (Frequence(Stars))
    rep_s,freq_s = (translate(Rep_s,data))
    DF1 = dataframe(numbers,rep_n,freq_n)
    DF2 = dataframe(stars,rep_s,freq_s)

    DF1.to_csv(f'DF1_{datetime.now().strftime('%f')}.csv')
    DF2.to_csv(f'DF2_{datetime.now().strftime('%f')}.csv')
```